# Merge multiple array to single array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this piece of code from which i wish to get a single array that contains all value.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM interest where interest='".$interest."' and userid!='".$myuserid."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $userid = $row["userid"];

                if($searchtype == 'both')
                    {
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM register where id='".$userid."' and  discover = 'on' and id!='".$myuserid."'";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) 
                            {
                                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
                                    {
                                        echo "<pre>";
                                        print_r($row2);
                                        echo "</pre>";
                                    }
                            }       
                    }
            }
    }
```

The o/p that i am getting is something like this

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [email] => A1
    [username] =>B1 
    [password] => C1
    [gender] => C1
)

Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [email] => A2
    [username] => B2
    [password] => C2
    [gender] => D2
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [email] => A3
    [username] => B3
    [password] => C3
    [gender] => D3
)
```

But i wish to get this all data in a single array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [email] => A1
             [username] =>B1 
             [password] => C1
             [gender] => C1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [email] => A2
            [username] => B2
            [password] => C2
            [gender] => D2
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [email] => A3
            [username] => B3
            [password] => C3
            [gender] => D3
        )
}
```

can anyone tell how i can do so

Comment: Can you update your question with sample output which you want to see?  Do you want there to be multiple `id` values in the array, or do you want one `id` entry with a collection of values?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen updated my post

Comment: One refactoring: if you need only `userid` from the first query, why can't u change your first query to `"SELECT userid FROM interest where interest='".$interest."' and userid!='".$myuserid."'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one array variable before while loop started like `$user_data = array();` and in inner loop you have to set  `$user_data[] = $row2;`

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $user_data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $userid = $row["userid"];
            if($searchtype == 'both') {
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM register where id='".$userid."' and  discover = 'on' and id!='".$myuserid."'";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                                    $user_data[] = $row2;
                                }
                        }       
                }
        }
   print_r($user_data);   //Print here your user_data outside the loop.
}
```

Comment: although i get the answer can u plz tell why the result can't be printed within the loop

Comment: You got the result in loop but it display individual array record and you want whole result in single array thats why need to create `$user_data` variables

Comment: in this post i had a part of my code, here i had displayed only one condition of if($searchtype == 'both') but i have 2 more condition based on searchtype and i wished to print the result of every condition separately, but if i print the result outside i won't be able to get the result acc to condition

Comment: If you have got answer of posted question then you can ask new question in new post it is better to give best answer

Answer (score 1):

Create an array variable like `$a=array();` at the start of your code

Get row value in array $a[]=your row value(while loop), then print this outside loop you will get all value in single array print like

```
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost near to your goal, you just need to define one array and save each row's data in it

```
// array which contains all rows data
$all_rows = array();                                //  <------ step 1
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)) 
{
   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
   {
      // every record data is stored here
      $all_rows[] = $row2;                          //  <------ step 2
   }
} 
if(!empty($all_rows))
{
      print_r($all_rows);
}else
{
     echo "do some thing else since zero records fetched";
}
```